# typescript copy function and preserve types

Tags: typescript

I am using p5.js with typescrtip.

In p5.js you have a p5 object where you can call

```js
let p5: P5; // it is assigned somwhere else but this does not matter for this question

p5.createCanves(400, 400);
p5.background("#fff");
p5.line(0, 0, 400, 400);
```

to draw a line from the top left corner to the bottom right corner of a white canves.

now I am trying to call these methodes without the `p5.` in front.

so far I have tried this:

```
let p5: P5;

const createCanvas = p5.createCanvas;
const background = p5.background;
const line = p5.line;

// or

const createCanvas = (() => { return p.createCanvas; })();
const background = (() => { return p.background; })();
const line = (() => { return p.line; })();
```

but p5.js does not allow these methodes to be acsessed before the methode `p5.setup` is called, and thus I am not allowed to assign the methodes to a variable.

next I tried just calling the methode:

```
const createCanvas = (x: number, y: number) => p5.createCanvas(x, y);
const background = (value: string) => p5.background(value);
const line = (x1: number, y1: number, x2: number, y2: number) => p5.line(x1, y1, x2, y2);
```

but this aproach is anoying if I have to do this with every function and I cannot reproduce overloads. For example the `background` methode has the following 6 signatures:

```
background(color: Color)
background(colorstring: string, a?: number | undefined)
background(gray: number, a?: number | undefined)
background(v1: number, v2: number, v3: number, a?: number | undefined)
background(values: number[])
background(image: Image, a?: number | undefined)
```

I have no idea how I could keep the Types and assign it to an variable. If there is a way pleas post an answer. My aproach would be

```
const backgroud = (color: Color)
                  (colorstring: string, a?: number | undefined)
                  (gray: number, a?: number | undefined)
                  (v1: number, v2: number, v3: number, a?: number | undefined)
                  (values: number[])
                  (image: Image, a?: number | undefined) => {
  if(color) return p5.background(color)
  if(colorstring) return p5.background(colorstring, number)
  if(gray) return p5.background(gray, a)
  if(v1) return p5.background(v1, v2, v3, a)
  if(values) return p5.background(values)
  if(image) return p5.background(image, a)
}
```

but this is obviously not valide Typescript

I also tried to somehow import the methodes in an other file

```
import {p5.*} from "./index"
```

but that is not possible as far as I know

Is there an easier aproach to my problem or should I just give up and write that god tamn `p5.`?

And is there a way to combine these 6 signatures into 1 variable?

Comment: can you check [triple-slash directives](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html) and see if they can help you with these scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[background](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsA26rIN4BQyxyCWOAXMgM5hSgDmA3AQL4sGiSyIoCSAWzgMUhEsgCuUTFVr0QzNgU7ho8JMgAKAVnxESAI0QBrBlHQSQAEwAUZbFCoYHASll1GLcUYSnzl23scOUZ3eQYAGmQ4AH4qEAkBA2hkAB9JawgYUAgrNxoPBS9DEzMLaxszOABPeMTkqCjYuqSU9ICsnLywz31iHz9y2wA3AEYWhqjhgCYJ6CmAZjnG6LjkBNbcdszskFz8kKK%205AGygJthuEwJCGplgG0AXQPCxW9S-wrgIREqQWEIE01hsGmkMlZOntugVwixWMoyCBaMgAA66AC8%20FY0WoWm0HERyNOnysVB09wA5MShhTHshMTYAHTMuBQBh3aIgaovcL0gB8qO0jOp52ZjNZ7JxWlZcAEEG41AAPOSqR8aY8%20S4CEA) function

[rect](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsA26rIN4BQyxyCWOAXMgM5hSgDmA3AQL4sGiSyIoBqEBGBz4iJAK5RMVWvRDM2BTuGjwkyAAoBWUSWRRBYABQAPKiHEBbAEbQANMgCe5q7agOA7i5v3kACwB%20bzdkAB9kcRAAEwgYUAgohzBMIOQLH1xwyJi4kASkqFT0kKzo2PjE5GtC4OgwiLLc-KqU2syGnIqASiptFj0DIVM2h2c0118vcYyHPxHkGLA4YEwADSKJ9uzyvMrF5cwATQ2M%20u2mqJ7NLRZWJTIQWmQABx0AXnxWZDhqa44Hp6DMC9LQAbQA5EDwQBdZAfIwAOiRcCgDGoVDgIEcXThAD4XloEUDEcjUb8fpoUXBLBBuNQADzaCFQ6G4rpKIA) function

you take a type from the library and assign it to a proxy arrow function.

Comment: how does typescript know it should hide the `...args: any[]` signature from me?

Comment: I ran into an issue with a function which has no number[]:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsA26rIN4BQyxyCWOAXMgM5hSgDmA3AQL4sGiSyIoBqEBGBz4iJAK5RMVWvRDM2BTuGjwkyAAoBWUSWR04IapjiQAFAA8qIcQFsARtAA0yAJ7W7jqC4BeAfg8HaGQAH2RxEAATCBhQCEiASiptFj0DIxNzADdBYSgqASEcJM0tFlYlMiMwZAAHHQBefFZkOGpSjhgIoWB0EH0oQ2NTCEtArxd3ZBsg72R-ceCwiOjYkHiSlIIukB6+gaHM0Zyi-ORCvM2y7e6wXv704fMAOle4KAZqKkNXAG0AXSuumQUAgYEk-Xqz0eRzM70+CXKQA

Comment: here's the updated solution https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsA26rIN4BQyxyCWOAXMgM5hSgDmA3AQL4sGiSyIoBqEBGBz4iJAK5RMVWvRDM2BTuGjwkyAAoBWUSWR04IapjiQAFAA8qIcQFsARtAA0yAJ7W7jqC4BeAfg8HaGQAH2RxEAATCBhQCEiASiptFj0DIxNzADdBYSgqASEcJM0tFlYlMiMwZAAHHQBefFZkOGpSjhgIoWB0EH0oQ2NTCEtArxd3ZBsg72R-ceCwiOjYkHiSlIIukB6+gaHM0Zyi-ORCvM2y7e6wXv704fMAOle4KAZqKkNXK91kKAQMCSfr1Z6PI5md6fBLlIA

Comment: I ran into another issue with a function with many optional parameters: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsA26rIN4BQyxyCWOAXMgM5hSgDmA3AQL4sGiSyIoBqEBGBz4iJAK5RMVWvRDM2BTuGjwkyAAoBWUSWRRBYABQAPKiHEBbAEbQANMgCe5q7agOA7i5v3kACwB+bzdkAB9kcRAAEwgYUAgohzBMIOQLH1xwyJi4kASkqFT0kKzo2PjE5GtC4OgwiLLc-KqU2syGnIqASiptFj0DIVM2h2c0118vcYyHPxHkGLA4YEwADSKJ9uzyvMrF5cwATQ2M+u2mqJ7NLRZWJTIQWmQABx0AXnxWZDhqa44YSJCYDoED6QzDaZuUbzKbFXyBNpnRoVJKtSF1UqdXYFE4lDo7ZrVXEY-EXBzWNFwrbI3ZXPoEAEgIEgsFDMzo9xOGHzOYchz7FbrRGYgl7CBLFbHYWk7q9G4MwFgYGgwbGAB0GrgUAY1CocBAjjpOkIxAMYEkoNeatVRi1Oq6tyAA

Comment: I have updated the answered with both functions. Had to typecast, maybe someone can point out how to avoid it